# Align to bottom RHS corner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

[image]

As you can see from the image I want to place the item of second textview to the right hand side bottom corner (position marked by a circle). How can I achieve this? Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/LeaveIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/leave_ic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#DC143C"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/leave_type"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:gravity="bottom|right"` on the Textview

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
```

so your widget xml will look like

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/leave_type"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change the second one as

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/leave_type"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```